# Can there exist a set that can not be partially ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that set is not partially ordered until we define some kind of ordering on it.
My question is about, if there is a set that can't be a poset at all.

Comment: Any set can be well ordered. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem

Comment: What would ever prevent a set from having a partial order defined on it?

Comment: Yes, there are posets of every cardinality

Comment: An equivalence relation is a partial order (at least in the non-strict sense).  What would stop you from just defining $a \leq a$ and no other relations (so the whole set is one big antichain)?  (If your definition of partial order uses the strict definition, then this would correspond to the empty relation)

Comment: @geetha290krm: Only is you accept the axiom of choice. This question is a whole lot simpler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any set can be well ordered. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem –
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1064504/geetha290krm

Answer (score 2):

The trivial order, where $x\leq x\iff x=x$, or rather, its strict version which is literally the empty relation, is easily seen to be a partial order on any set.

You can argue that a partial order is by definition non-empty, and there are merits to accepting or to rejecting this definition, in which case $\varnothing$ cannot be partially ordered, but for trivial and silly reasons.